# Field of view for a fisheye camera

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera, projection, camera-calibration

I would like to know a general formula which relates the field-of-view (FoV) to the size of an image and focal length.

The FoV formula for standard cameras is (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view))

[image: formula]

where *f* is the focal length.
That formula can be derived from the relation [image: formula] which relates the distance between the image point and the principal point, *r*, and the angle between the principal axis and the incoming ray, [image: formula], which reads:

[image: formula]

However, the above formula only works for standard cameras with perspective projection. Wide-angle fisheye cameras can have different relations [image: formula], see for instance [here](https://oulu3dvision.github.io/calibgeneric/Kannala_Brandt_calibration.pdf) different projections.

The only example in the web I found about FoV for fisheye cameras is in this [page](https://vrphotography.com/data/pages/askexperts/pano/fovfisheye.html), where they say that the FoV is given by

[image: formula]

which would be consistent with the above reasoning assuming the equisolid angle projection from  [this paper](https://oulu3dvision.github.io/calibgeneric/Kannala_Brandt_calibration.pdf).

Is it safe to assume that we can compute the FoV just by inverting the relation [image: formula] for each specific projection, as done with standard perspective projection? Is there any rigorous proof for that?

Comment: What are you worried about? Is your question "For fisheye camera, is it possible that several different `theta` are projected to the same `r`?" ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally (at least, for fisheye), radial directional projection function describes
one-to-one correspondence between `r` and `theta` (`r` increases as `theta` increases) **for actual range of `r`**.

Therefore, if the function is given as
r = F(theta),
you will be able to define the inverse:
theta = F<sup>-1</sup>(r)
**for actual range of `r`**.

If the above is not true for a camera, such camera will not be called as "fisheye", I think.

Comment: Thanks, that made it more clear. In general then, it is given by the inverse, as FoV = 2 F^(-1)(image_size/2).